# Use Signalr to have a facebook like notification system

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, push-notification, signalr

I want to implement a facebook like notification system in ASP.NET MVC 3 : notifications are sent to a specific user to notify him for an action on one of his items.

Is signalr suited for such requirement?
How could i send a notification to a specific user (all opened sessions of this user) using SignalR?

Edit

Ok, Here what i did

In the client side

```
$(function () {
// Proxy created on the fly
var chat = $.connection.chat;
var username = '@Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name';
// Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
chat.addMessage = function (message) {
     $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
};
// Start the connection
$.connection.hub.start(function (){
    chat.join(username);
});

});
```

In the server side

```
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Join(string username)
    {
        AddToGroup(username);
    }
}
```

And every time i need to notify a user in the controller i do the following:

```
IConnectionManager connectionManager = AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
dynamic clients = connectionManager.GetClients<Chat>();
clients[username].addMessage("test");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is appropriate for this or you use polling, those are the two choices.

Heres a brand new video from today on this:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Damian-Edwards-and-David-Fowler-Demonstrate-SignalR?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: thx Adam, do you think the solution i posted in the end of my post scale well? Thx

Comment: Your controller should take IConnectionManager as an injected dependency into its controller. You shouldn't call Resolve() really anywhere else but a controller factory. Use some DI container (unity for example - unity.mvc3 nuget package) and use Constructor injection to inject into your controller. Ensure if you have a Dispose method on your concrete implementation of IConnectionManager that you tell unity to dispose of it when done by using the HierarchicalLifetimeManager. Set a breakpoint to ensure dispose is getting called (only if you are implementing IDisposable)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, SignalR is a good choice for that. Take a look at the documentation regarding Hubs ([server](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) and [JS client](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs)).

You need to implement the server logic to associate your client's session with SignalR's session. You can use groups to notify all the open sessions of each user.

Comment: @user1236014 When a user connects you need to add his SignalR session to a group with his username/identifier. Every time you need to notify a user you just broadcast a message to his group (this guarantees that all open sessions will be notified). Take a look at this example, it might help you: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/12/06/Using-SignalR-to-broadcast-a-slide-deck.aspx

Comment: thx nmat, the solution i wrote in my post works fine. Do you think it the better one? do you think it scales good?