# SignalR can't find AddToGroup method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I'm building a hub which should send message to specific user and this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468513/use-signalr-to-have-a-facebook-like-notification-system) and this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089386/signalr-push-notifications-to-all-browser-instances-of-single-authenticated-user) would work perfectly, only I can't find AddToGroup method, I know a lot things have changed in version 0.5, is this one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a `Groups` property now on the `Hub` class that you could use to add users to. The [documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs) also illustrates this:

```
public class MyHub : Hub, IDisconnect
{
    public Task Join()
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "foo");
    }

    public Task Send(string message)
    {
        return Clients["foo"].addMessage(message);
    }

    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        return Clients["foo"].leave(Context.ConnectionId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed, but Groups.Add takes two parametars and I don't know connectionID

Comment: so both parametars should be the same? since I want just one user per group?

Comment: If you want one user per group then indeed, they should be the same